# Error when filtering on Guid in OData query

Tags: filter, odata, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to filter my OData query result to retrieve the Activity records related to the current Record Id only. I'm using the code below:

```
var RecordId = parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
var options = "$select=Subject&$filter=RegardingObjectId eq guid'" + RecordId + "'";
```

However, this produces an error below:
[image]

How can I correctly filter on a guid ?

EDIT:

Here's my full function:

```
function retrieveActivities() {
   ///<summary>
   /// Retrieves Activities by passing a filter to the SDK.RestEndpointPaging.RetrieveRecords function
   ///</summary>
   clearRelatedGrid();
   var number = parseInt(numberOfActivitiesToRetrieve.options[numberOfActivitiesToRetrieve.selectedIndex].value, 10);
   var RecordId = parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
   var options = "$select=Subject&$filter=RegardingObjectId/Id eq (guid'" + RecordId + "');

   SDK.REST.retrieveMultipleRecords("ActivityPointer", options, retrieveActivitiesCallBack, function (error) { alert(error.message); }, ActivitiesRetrieveComplete);
  }
```

Comment: The URL being called is needed, you can grab it through the F12 tool

Comment: I apologize I'm not familiar with how I can get the URL. I already have the Developer tools open on Chrome. Can you guide me to it's location ?

Comment: uhm in the error line you are seeing, there should be a link on the right. click it, it should bring you to the relevant row of the "Network" tab. right click to copy the url. EDIT: glad to see you solved the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filtering by lookups goes by `fieldname/Id eq (guid'<your guid>')` so this should work:

```
var RecordId = parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
var options = "$select=Subject&$filter=RegardingObjectId/Id eq (guid'" + RecordId + "')";
```

Comment: Thank you, I Tried that but my browser console showed: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" for that line of code

Comment: Amend the question with the full ODATA url you're using to query, something else is wrong

Comment: Done. Please check my updated question. I tried removing the filter and testing again, it worked fine. That's why i concluded it's the filter's problem

Comment: My mistake.. left the statement without the ending quotes. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi @Alex:
I trying call to filter by an property which is guid:: `Service?$filter=c8e735a52bd94c40b2d32d572eaa6884_Contract_Contractid eq (guid'f1c6798a-1b31-4312-a663-a3ec47f06f3c')` 

i am getting below error



`Unrecognized 'Edm.String' literal 'guid'f1c6798a-1b31-4312-a663-a3ec47f06f3c'' at '57' in 'c8e735a52bd94c40b2d32d572eaa6884_Contract_Contractid eq (guid'f1c6798a-1b31-4312-a663-a3ec47f06f3c')?$filter=c8e735a52bd94c40b2d32d572eaa6884_Contract_Contractid eq (guid'f1c6798a-1b31-4312-a663-a3ec47f06f3c')'.`

Can you please help me to understand what is wrong in my call ? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I struggled with the same thing using the new Web API v8.2. I know this was asked a year ago but for anyone who stumbles on this today, this would have fixed the problem for me:

```
var options = "$select=Subject&$filter=RegardingObjectID eq " + RecordId;
```

Simply compare the guid value (as a string) to the object ID directly. Don't try to tell the API its a guid. Its smart enough now to know that. I hope this helps someone else using v8.2.

See here for a more in depth explanation
https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/conorssnippetdiary/archive/2015/12/03/web-api-preview-unrecognized-39-edm-string-39-literal

Answer (score 0):

I am using this OData query filter in my D365 portal.

For Guid filtering

```
var userId = '{{ user.id }}';
var contactfilteroption = "contactid eq guid'"+userId+"'";
var odataUrI = "https://yourportal.com/_odata/contacts?$filter="+encodeURIComponent(contactfilteroption);
```

For string filtering

```
var couponcode = eventdiscountamount.target.value; 
var couponcodefilteroption = "stdsscouponcode eq '"+couponcode+"'";
var odataUrI = "https://yourportal.com/_odata/stdssdiscounts?$filter="+encodeURIComponent(couponcodefilteroption);
```